# How does one update ListView's children?

Tags: dart, flutter

My goal is to be able to add 'dummy' ListTiles to a ListView when pressing a Floating Action Button.

```
class Notes extends StatefulWidget{

  _NotesState createState() => new _NotesState();
}

class _NotesState extends State<Notes>{

  List<ListTile> notes =[];

  void addNewNote(){
     setState((){
        notes.add(new ListTile(title: new Text("Broccolli")));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
     return new Scaffold(
       appBar: new AppBar(title: "NOTES"),
       body: new Stack(
       children: <Widget>[
        // The notes
        new Container(
          child: new ListView(
            children: notes,
          )
        ),
        // The add notes button
        new FloatingActionButton(
          tooltip: 'Add a note',
          onPressed: addNewNote, 
        )
       ],
      ),
     );
  }
}
```

When I press the Floating Action Button the new ListTile gets added to the list, but the ListView does not get updated. I presume I am missing/missunderstanding a basic concept.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest issue is that you're passing a list of widgets directly as the children of Notes. When Flutter does a rebuild, it looks at all the widgets and checks to see if they've changed; it then only propagates changes town branches that have changed.

Because you're passing the exact same list and flutter likes to do things in an optimized way, it's only checking if the ListView's children list is the exact same list - and because you're passing in the same list each time, it doesn't see the difference.

One option is that you could simply recreate a new list each time (by wrapping `notes` in `new List.from(notes, growable: false)`. But that sort of misses the point.

Your widget should only be storing the information needed to create widgets, and then the actual creation of widgets should be done in the `build` function.

So that would look like this:

```
class Notes extends StatefulWidget {
  _NotesState createState() => new _NotesState();
}

class _NotesState extends State<Notes> {
  List<String> notes = [];

  void addNewNote() {
    setState(() {
      notes.add("Broccolli ${notes.length}");
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Notes: $notes");
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("NOTES")),
      body: new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          // The notes
          new Container(
            child: new ListView(
                children: notes
                    .map((string) => new ListTile(title: new Text(string)))
                    .toList(growable: false)),
          ),
          // The add notes button
          new FloatingActionButton(
            tooltip: 'Add a note',
            onPressed: addNewNote,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Storing the listTiles directly does work, but it quite likely wouldn't if you started to have more complex widgets (in particular stateful widgets).