# How to dynamically add Children to Scaffold Widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Let's say, I have a chat screen that looks like this.

[image]

Now, when the user clicks the "Press when ready" button, the method `fetchNewQuestion()` is called.

My intention is that this will make a HTTP request, and display the result using

```
_buildUsersReply(httpResponse);
```

But, the problem is that this return must be made inside the current scaffold's widget as a child under the existing children, so that it is built at the bottom with the previous ones still there. The result would be like this:

[image]

You can find my complete code [here](https://gist.github.com/Eshpelin/c19a0ab47a8f0beca9546f2aa1b5426b).

Is this possible to be done pro-grammatically? Or do I have to change the concept of how I do this?

[Update, I now understand that my approach above is wrong and I have to use a listview builder. CurrentStatus below shows my progress towards achieving that goal.]

---

## Current status:

I have built a list of Widgets:

```
List<Widget> chatScreenWidgets = [];
```

And on setState, I am updating that with a new Widget using this:

```
setState(() { chatScreenWidgets.add(_buildUsersReply("I think there were 35 humans and one horse.")); });
```

Now at this point, I am not sure how to pass the widget inside the scaffold. I have written some code that does not work. For instance, I tried this:

[image]

Code in the image below and in the gist [here](https://gist.github.com/Eshpelin/76a0d96167f0b0afc1796950bca3777c):

[image]

Comment: If your scaffold is in a stateful widget, you can just assign the children to a variable of type List<Widget>, and then when the request comes back, just call setState(() => _scaffoldChildren = ...) or something like that.

Comment: Yes it is a Stateful Widget. But I am not being able to understand how to implement the `_scaffoldChildren = ...` idea. Any further explanation would be nice. 

Additionally, when I tried to convert my children: <Widget> to children: List<Widget>, I face the error `The operator < isn't defined for the class Type` and `An equality expression can't be an operand of another equality`. 

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is a complete example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676360/how-does-one-update-listviews-children

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for future reference, here is what I really needed to do:

**1.** Create a list of widgets

`List<Widget> chatScreenWidgets = [];`

**2.** Inside my method, I needed to use a setState in order to add elements to that list. Every widget I add to this will be displayed on ths Scaffold.

```
`setState(() {
       chatScreenWidgets.add(_buildUsersReply("Some Text"));
    });`
```

**3.** And then, load that inside my Scaffold, I used an itemBuilder in order to return a list of widgets to my ListView. I already had that ListView (where I was manually adding children). Now this just returns them through the setState method inside my business logic method (in this case, `fetchNewQuestion()`).

```
body: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0),
        child: new ListView.builder(
          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25),
          itemCount: chatScreenWidgets.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int itemCount) {
              return chatScreenWidgets[itemCount];
            }
        ),
      ),
          ],
        ),
      );`
```

I hope this helps future flutter engineers!

Answer (score 0):

forget about the scaffold the idea is about what you really want to change, lets say it is 
a list and your getting the data from an array if you update the array, then the list will update,if it is another type widgets then you can handle it in a different way i will edit this answer if you clarify what each part does in your widget as i cant read your full code.

---

1. first you have to create an object with two attributes one is the type of the  row(if it is a user replay or other messages) and the second attribute is the string or the text.
2. now create a global list in the listview class from the above object, so you get the data from the user or even as a news and you create a new object from the above class and add your data to it and add it to the list.
3. item builder returns a widget so according to the the widget that you return the row will be set , so according to the data in the object call one of your functions that return the views like _buildUsersReply(string text).

if you have any other question you can ask :) if this what you need please mark it as the answer.

Comment: I understand. Let me know which portion of the code you would like to know more about. Just to give you a basic idea, I have a `_buildUsersReply();` widget builder that takes a string and creates a chat bubble. 

Similarly, my main Scaffold/Widget is in this link (https://gist.github.com/Eshpelin/c19a0ab47a8f0beca9546f2aa1b5426b#file-my-original-scaffold), and I have commented where I want to build the chat bubble within this. Currently I can manually add them. Just want to automate how this works.

I have pointed these out at bottom of previous file.

Comment: https://medium.com/@DakshHub/flutter-displaying-dynamic-contents-using-listview-builder-f2cedb1a19fb

Comment: ok check this link above its listview builder when i saw your code i found you are just using listview with coded children only , so basically you have to add listview builder and at item builder you will have an index to the row i will edit the answer to detailed what you should do

Comment: Thank you. Can you please check the question again? In the last portion, I have added content that tries to mimic your advice of using an item builder. I am trying to create a list of widgets, and updating that using setState(). Major problem now is how can I return/display that inside the original scaffold (how to write that itemBuilder to accept my list of widgets). You can find the current code at the last end of the question above in detail.

Comment: Please disregard. I have solved the issue with the Widget. Thank you very much!